# Bootstrap Modal body out of order

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

[Bootstrap modal out of order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8viTY.png)

[image]

As seen from the above image, you will get all knowledge what my problem is.

```html
<a href="" data-target="#myModalView" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-sm btn-default"><span class="fa fa-eye"></span> View</a>


<div class="modal fade" id="myModalView" role="document">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">View Details</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <h3>jgnsdvolsgnvolkfngoelkfsngvje;alfnvojfelsnvo;eaflsnboa;fljnbjdfbnkjdfbkjfbkjfbvjkfjvnsjfvjsanvjsnvjsvjnbskjvsfjvnsfjn</h3>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```css
     .wordwrapclass{
      word-wrap: break-word;
     }
```

```html
    <div class="row wordwrapclass">
                                <h3>jgnsdvolsgnvolkfngoelkfsngvje;alfnvojfelsnvo;eaflsnboa;fljnbjdfbnkjdfbkjfbkjfbvjkfjvnsjfvjsanvjsnvjsvjnbskjvsfjvnsfjn</h3>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add `word-wrap:break-word` rules to your `modal-body` class